# Android emulator freezes the system on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: android, android-emulator

my android emulator was working super fine in Ubuntu 19.04. but after getting this update it's slow while running any application and even it freezes my system while running applications. I have Core i9 Hexa Core CPU with 16GB of Ram and 3NVME SSDs are working. Every other stuff is fine but I am stuck at here